# Polymer custom elements and Polymer-gestures

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, polymer, gestures

I would like to add listener event on a Polymer custom element with Polymer-gestures.

This is my sample code :

**- my-custom-element.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-custom-element" attributes="width height color">
    <template>
        <canvas id="canvas"  width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" style="background-color: {{color}}"  touch-action="none"></canvas>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            width: '',
            height: '',
            color: ''
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**- my-custom-parent-element.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../polymer-gestures/polymer-gestures.html">

<polymer-element name="my-custom-parent-element">
    <template>
        <my-custom-element width="300px" height="200px" color="yellow"></my-custom-element>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
        ready: function() {

            this.myCustomElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('my-custom-element');

            var events = [
                // base events
                'down',
                'up',
                'trackstart',
                'track',
                'trackend',
                'tap',
                'hold',
                'holdpulse',
                'release'
            ];

            events.forEach(function(en) {
                PolymerGestures.addEventListener(this.myCustomElement, en, function (inEvent) {
                ...
            });
        }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I have an error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_pgListeners' of undefined

In debug mode when I add the event listener in my-custom-parent-element.html, I checked the value of the myCustomElement variable, and it's null.

How could I add the event listener on the myCustomElement variable ???

Answer (score 0):

The querySelector in the following line is misspelled:

```
this.myCustomElement = this.shadowRoot.querrySelector('my-custom-element');
```

Try with `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('my-custom-element');`.

Comment: It's not the right correction of the issue, I just made a typing error in stackoverflow